# CodeName One List/Multi-List text into multiple rows

Tags: codenameone

is it possible to break long text into multiple lines in list or multi list, im aware that in Codename one label is always a single line. How can i achieve that? do i need to use renderer ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

MultiList supports up to 4 lines but you need to determine them in advance (text doesn't wrap implicitly). Lists are problematic for wrapping see: http://www.codenameone.com/3/post/2013/12/deeper-in-the-renderer.html

You can use `SpanLabel`'s and `SpanButton`'s in a `Container` instead.